# CoreResultsWebPart not working anymore in 2019

Tags: search, 2019

I am currently working on a migrated 2019-farm. Migration was 2010->2013->2016->2019 in one flow.

Now, I find the old `CoreResultsWebPart` not showing any results at all. Search is working fine and if I remove the `CoreResultsWebPart` and replace by using the new `ResultScriptWebPart` results are displayed.

Is it possible that the old `CoreResultsWebPart` is not working at all in 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No": `CoreResultsWebPart` generally works, even in 2019. (This was my question, anyhow.)

The problem in my case seems to be that it can access `SearchScopes` which might be existing in the farm or not (depending on whether SSA was migrated or not) but I feel most of them do not work anymore (Some do, though). They `SearchScopes` can be used (if they were migrated) but can't be modified I'll go and replace all `CoreResultsWebPart`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are migrating from 2010 there will be several webparts that no longer function in 2019.  These must be removed and replaced with 2019 webparts as you discovered.

Comment: That's not it. I finally managed to get a simple `CoreResultsWebPart` working. The "error" has something to do with the migrated search configuration and this particular WebPart. I'm still investigating, though.